# Android - Java - Get Access to TimePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, string, android-timepicker

Hi I currently have a TimePickerDialog:

```
 TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet( TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute ) {
              c.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay );
              c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, minute );
              String hour = Integer.toString(hourOfDay);
              String min = Integer.toString(minute);
              String timeStamp = hour + ":" + min;

            }
          };
```

However I just want to know how can I gain access to the TimeStamp String outside of the method ? As I need to use it again to send it into another method which inputs it into a JSON Object. I did try making the String Final or Public but just got errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a field to the class named timeStamp and change it.

Example:

```
public class Outside
{
private String timeStamp;

 TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet( TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute ) {
              c.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay );
              c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, minute );
              String hour = Integer.toString(hourOfDay);
              String min = Integer.toString(minute);
              timeStamp = hour + ":" + min;

            }
          };
}
```

I removed `String timeStamp` "String" because you now refer to the field.

Now timeStamp will contains `hour + ":" + min` when `onTimeSet` is called.

P.S You cannot make it `final` since it will change everytime `onTimeSet` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, Defiantly solved my problem ! :)